# Tools for orchestration of web services

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest

Let's say I have many web services (REST or normal HTTP request) and I want to define in which order they should be called. I want the order to be easily configured (through XML files) and return error responses in case they are called in the wrong way.

When I say tools I mean some framework in Java. The framework should have good documentation with examples.

I don't want only a name but I would like pros/cons - why should I choose one or another.

EDIT: I forgot to mention it has to be an OpenSource (or any free licence for unlimited usage). And the application will probably run on GoogleAppEngine or Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to orchestrate long running processes then what you need is a BPEL engine.. if not you can go for an Enterprise Service Bus..

[WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.org/library/esb) is an open source Enterprise Service Bus and [WSO2 BPS](http://wso2.org/library/bps) is a business process server built on top of Apache ODE.

eBAY using WSO2 ESB to process 1 Billion messages per day.

Disclaimer: I am an architect from WSO2.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need a Service Bus.

Bea's Aqualogic was a good one.

Pros: integrated with weblogic, support XQuery for message manipulation. Has persistency queues. Flows are defined within it's user interface.

Cons: not so easy to use. Costly.

Regards,

M.

PS: On the pros I would add Bea's good support, but since now they're Oracle I doubt that quality will be high as in the past

EDIT: ops, OpenSource solution needed. So this answer was actually wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I added the OpenSource restriction after your response. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering how "WSO2 ESB" or "WSO2 BPS" will address the issues presented in the original question.

The more I look into that project the more it looks to me it is BPEL driven which will probably not play good with "REST/normal http".

I believe Apache Camel should be a good start point.

Comment: Well. I started with those WSO2 things too, than tried Apache Camel. It was too complex for my purpose or it didn't fit too much. After that I tried a simple state machine (Commons SCXML) and that did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I built a Business Protocol implementation that resulted in a full MVC Framework implementation several years ago (http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2006/11/scxml-as-controller-language-for-web.html). Rahul the main developer for SCXML project was very helpful. I was hoping that after so many years there was something better out there.

Comment: Just to report back that we are successfully using Camel for REST Service Orchestration, and beyond. A proof of concept (full tutorial) can be found in http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-quartz-camel-and-spring-for.html